# What is the data loading time in inmemory technologies MSBI?

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2012

I have read like column store and vertipaq are in memory storage option in sql server 2012.So, It will be stored in RAM.I just want to know that, when it will be stored to RAM?whether  the starting time of sql server or when we query the data from them?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Columnstore is not an in-memory storage option. It is more a memory and access pattern optimized on disk storage option. The data gets read into memory (the buffer pool) when a query requests it. There it stays as long as the room is not needed for something else, following the standard cache aging rules.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply.What about the tablular model in analysis service 2012 and powerpivot?These two are inmeomory technologies right?When the data wil be loaded into memory in these two types?

Answer (score 0):

For SSAS Tabular, the "model" will be loaded into RAM immediately after processing and upon starting the SSAS Tabular instance.

For PowerPivot run from a client workstation, the "model" will be loaded into RAM immediately after pulling data into the model (for new powerpivot workbooks) or upon opening the file (for existing powerpivot workbooks).

For PowerPivot published to Sharepoint, the "model" will be loaded into RAM immediately after the workbook is published.  Sharepoint has its own PowerPivot-version of SSAS tabular instance  running behind the scenes.  When a new PowerPivot workbook is published to SharePoint, the "model" is extracted from the workbook and loaded in this PowerPivot-specific SSAS tabluar instance.  After that, there are several configuration options that dictate how long the model remains in memory. This is because the access patterns are quite different between PowerPivot models and SSAS tabular models.  Kevin Donavan had a good presentation on this during TechEd2012 North America ([link to video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=&s=kevin%2bdonovan) - can't remember which one it was)